# Метка [top], нужна ли она?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Вопрос такой, увидел, что есть 15 вопросов с меткой [top](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top). Описания метки нет. Смысл от неё - непонятен. Предлагаю убрать такую метку, так как она не несет какой-то полезной информации. Видимо, пользователи, которые её используют хотят лишь подчеркнуть важность вопроса для них, но раз он задан, понятно, что вопрос для них важный.

Comment: Удалил метку с вопросов по SQL TOP и прочих, где она ничего не добавляет. На будущее, предлагая удаление метки, нужно изучать, как она используется, почему она представляет проблему. То, что смысл метки непонятен - недостаточное основание для удаления.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight , так я видимо как раз выборку из вопросов, где она не по теме была. И поэтому сделал вывод, что она бессмысленная. Вынес на обсуждение.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Б**о**льшая часть вопросов с меткой [top](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top) относится к Linux утилите с одноимённым названием [top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

Удалять метку точно не стоит. По-хорошему, следует добавить описание, хотя бы краткое. А саму метку можно переименовать, чтобы стала менее неоднозначной. Например, как на enSO - [`top-command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-command).